# python how to run a function everyday at specific time, but can also be terminated

Tags: python, timer, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I'm new to explore how to do this in python. What I want to do is run a function every business day at a specific time, e.g., say at 14:55, just 5 minutes before the stock market closes in China. This function will pull some data from a stock market data feeding API and do some simple calculations to generate a signal(-1 means to short, +1 means to long, 0 means don't do anything). I'm not sending the signal yet to make a trade now. I'm just saving the signals everyday to a file locally. Thus, I might be able to collect the signals for 2 weeks or any time I feel like to stop this scheduler.

I notice that `APScheduler` module being suggested quite often. But I tried it, didn't find a way to make the scheduler stop running 2 weeks after. I only find ways to set up a scheduler to run, maybe every 10 minutes, but it will just keep running a specified function every 10 minutes and can't be stopped programmally,  but only through pressing `Ctrl+C`? For example, I want to run a function every 10 minutes for 6 times, in `APScheduler`, I didn't see anyway to specify the '6 times' argument. Or I want to run a function every 10 minutes until 1 hour later. I didn't see the '1 hour later' or 'at 16:30' argument either. How to do it?

Currently, I'm doing it this way:

```
def test_timer():
    '''
    Uses datetime module.
    '''
    running = 1
    stop_time = datetime.now() + timedelta(seconds=60)
    while running:

        print('I\'m working...')
        time.sleep(5)
        running = datetime.now() < stop_time

    print('Goodbye!')
```

Edited: I'm using python 3.6 in Windows 10.

Comment: If you are using linux an easy way would be to use a crontab that will come to run your code when you need it

Comment: @Squick Lol question never include `OS` definition

Comment: @dsgdfg this is why I said "if"

Comment: You are correct but i am talking about @StayFoolish

Comment: I'm not familliar with Advanced Python Scheduler.
But:
On their documentation (https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)I found: 
APScheduler has three built-in scheduling systems you can use:

 - Cron-style scheduling (with optional start/end times)
 - Interval-based execution (runs jobs on even intervals, with optional start/end times)
 - One-off delayed execution (runs jobs once, on a set date/time)
So it provides stop time, isn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this example

```
from datetime import datetime

from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler


def job_function():
    print("Hello World")

sched = BackgroundScheduler()

# Schedule job_function to be called every 1 second
# FIXME: Do not forget to change end_date to actual date
sched.add_job(job_function, 'interval', seconds=1, end_date="2017-09-08 12:22:20")

sched.start()
```

**Update #1**

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

def job_function():
    print("Hello World")

# Here, you can generate your needed days
dates = ["2017-09-08 13:30:20", "2017-09-08 13:31:20", "2017-09-08 13:32:20"]
sched = BackgroundScheduler()                      

for date in dates:
    sched.add_job(job_function, "date", next_run_time=date)

sched.start()
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't notice that I could add `end_date` argument. Is there a way to specify the scheduler to run every business day? Or run for 9 times.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a problem for crontab in Linux or Task Scheduler in Windows.

Comment: About mac os ??

Comment: crontab is present on MacOS
https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/schedule-jobs-with-crontab-on-mac-osx.html